# Sum of constants convergence rate

Tags: calculus, limits, number-theory, summation

Is it true that, if $a_i \leq 1,\; i=1,..,n$ then for large $n$ holds:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_i = C n + O(g(n)),\; C \in [0,1]
\end{equation}
and $g(n) \leq \sqrt{n}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes this is true. This statement holds for *every* $g$.

---

*Small note:* We can easily see that
\begin{equation}
\sum_{x=1}^{n}a_i \le n \iff \sum_{x=1}^{n}a_i =Cn,\quad C\in[0,1].
\end{equation}
The first expression seems more efficient to use.

---

If $g=O(n)$, the $O(g)$-term then becomes unnecessary, since  for suffiently large $n$, it does not affect our leading growth-term $n$. Writing this compact in big $O$-notation,
\begin{equation}
\sum_{x=1}^{n}a_i =O(n).
\end{equation}
If $n=O(g)$ the statement is still true, but yields a worse bound. If $n=O(g)$, we may write\begin{equation}
\sum_{x=1}^{n}a_i =O(g(n)).
\end{equation}

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer!
For example, we know that C = 0.34567 ...
Can we say that g (n) <= sqrt (n)?
Or does it depend on the distribution of a_i?

Comment: @dmp92 No this does not seem correct in general. Take $a_i=1$, so the sum equals $n$ and let $g(n)=k$ be constant. We have $n=0.34567\cdot n+O(k)$, which is equivalent to $\lvert n-0.34567\cdot n\rvert\le\lvert k\rvert$. The problem is that if we let $n\to\infty$, the left hand side $ n-0.34567\cdot n$ is not bounded.

Comment: Thanks! You helped me a lot